# Post preview shows capital letters in tags, but actual post does not

Tags: bug, status-completed, editing

[this-tag-is-in-all-caps](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/this-tag-is-in-all-caps) and shows as such in the preview when editing/composing.  After posting, however, the post will show the tag with lowercase letters.  A very minor failure of the WYSIWYG, but ideally this wouldn't happen.

I assume the posted version is correct, so it's the previewer that has the bug.

Repro'd on Windows XP:

- Chrome 13.0.782.109 beta-m

Repro'd on Windows 7 x64:

- Chrome 16.0.912.41 beta-m
- Chrome 13.0.782.109 beta-m
- Firefox 5.0.1
- IE 9

Comment: Belongs on [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) as this is not a Gaming problem. Furthermore, I don't see this problem happen on Win7 x64 - FF 8.0a1 so could you include OS, Browser information and a screenshot?

Comment: @Tom No, the SE people decided these questions are fine on site Metas.  You're right about the info though, adding.  (Screenshot is overkill, the problem is clear.)

Comment: +1 Sure, but you will get more attention on Meta.SO...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tag sanitizer routine (which, among other things, includes lowercasing) wasn't run on over `[tag:...]` links in the preview. That's fixed in the next build.

Comment: Cool, thanks :)